# Auto add character when read text from table in Word

Tags: c#, string, ms-word

I don't know why when I read text from a cell of table (in Word) -> result is a unexpected output.

Particularly,

```
string s = tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text;
```

When I debug, `tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text` equals `"123\r\a"`. But when i assign it to `s`, `s` equals `"123\r\r\a"` !!!

Could someone help me to figure out this situation?

Comment: Where are you reading this value (Seeing the debugged value?) Have you modified your environments escape sequences at all?

Comment: I read from cell of table (in Word). Value in this cell is "123" and i haven't modified escape character. I just read normally. Did I read by the wrong way?

Comment: I have no idea, I'm wondering if your looking at the wrong value in the debugger, when you are looking at the value you should see a magnifying glass icon, click this to see the real value.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I checked it many times.
I fixed it by replace `"\r"` character by `String.Empty` -> problem solved.
Now, I just want to figure out why it happened. So strange.